# Find a cutoff value in R

Tags: r, density-plot

I need to help with finding a cut-off point/value in the one numeric variable. Is there some way to find this cut-off point/value??? And it draws to density plot.

For example on this data:

```
df = c(runif(100, min = 0.5, max = 10.3))
polygon(density(column), col="red", border="black")
```

[image]

Comment: When you say cutoff do you mean a place to cut the graph off, or simply a point to draw a line to distinguish between two sides?

Comment: A point to draw a line to distinguish between two sides. This point will specify splitting data on 0 and 1. It means that if I find out cut off value of this range, for example, cut off is 5,6 - in this point will split data

Comment: do you mean the median value? like try abline(v=median(column)) on this plot?

Comment: It sounds like you need to find a local minimum in the dataset.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by a cut-off value. Usually cut-off values have a criterion behind their definition. For example: if the plot represented a mixture of two e.g. normal distributions (which I know is not the case in your plot), a criterion could be: the value that minimizes the expected error of deciding from which of the two distributions a particular observation came.
What's your criterion to define the cut-off value?

Comment: The core that you provide is not very useful. 1. You create `df` but never use it.  2. Your code refers to `column` but you do not provide it.  3, Your code calls `polygon` but that only makes sense when there is an existing plot. Your code does not plot anything else first.